# Flutter cannot be installed on Mac

Tags: macos, flutter

When I tried to install flutter on Mac(Big Sur), It gave the below error.

```
"dart" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

I used the Flutter SDK 2.0.5 (the latest one) via this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)

P.S: actually Mac downloads the flutter SDK & capable of unzipping it. But when I run `flutter --version` after setting the path for a flutter on the terminal it gave the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working. All I had to do is `give permission` for the Terminal app in the `Developer Tools section` in `Security & Privacy in System Preferences`

Answer (score 1):

open your MacOS Settings -> Security & Privacy

near the bottom, you should say a message asking you if you want to allow dart. tick the option and you should be good to go

Comment: Can you please elaborate? It'd be better if you can mention the specific section in Security & Privacy.

Comment: Thanks, Actually, I had to give permission for the Terminal app in the Developer Tools section in Security & Privacy.

Comment: here's a more techy way of doing it: follow [this steps](https://support.apple.com/en-qa/guide/mac-help/mh40616/mac). To locate dart app, open your terminal and type `which dart` then navigate to the `bin` where dart is located then, still in the terminal, type `open .` that will open finder at that location, from there follow the steps described in the link above ;)